# WebView cache clearing issue

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, asihttprequest

In my application i am using ASIHTTPRequest to download the webpage. In that webpage i download the images which gets changed everyday. And my application works for online as well as offline mode (i.e when there is network i download the webpage and in background i store it in the DocDir). In offline mode i store the contents of the web Page into the DocumentsSirectory.Now the issue is that, when i download the page and view it in the online mode it loads the latest images from the webpage, but when i go into the offline mode the webview loads the previously loaded page (i.e. old images). I tried clearing cache of the webView but didn't seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

here are some nice tricks to clear cache from a uiviewview

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"WebKitCacheModelPreferenceKey"];
```

also

```
   [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
```